# Datatables.net - Export to Excel is showing error while customizing

Tags: jquery, datatables, sharepoint-online, web-parts

I am using SPFx, typescript and datatables.net for my webpart and I want to export to excel and do some customization on data like align to left.
Exporting is working fine but while I add code for customization its showing error.
here is my code:

```
 window["JSZip"] = JSZip;
      $('#trackerDataTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
          {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: '<i></i>&nbsp;Export to Excel &nbsp;',
            filename: 'Timecards',
            extension: '.xlsx',
            exportOptions: {
              columns: ':visible'
            },
            customize: function (xlsx) {
              debugger;
              var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
              $('row c[r^="C"]', sheet).attr('s', '50');
            }
          },
        ]
});
```

Here in the above code xlsx.xl is showing  below error :

[image]

It would be great if you can help me here to make it work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You included the JSZip extension in your `<head></head>` correct

Comment: Yes @BeerusDev. and I can export it but I cannot customize it.

Comment: Can you provide your full code? Or atleast a test case: For example, here is an example on the DataTables website using [Orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-orthogonal.html) and here is a JS Bin showing how to [Change the style of the spreadsheet](http://live.datatables.net/jijumeji/1/edit)

Comment: I created separate function for it and it started working. Thank you @BeerusDev for  your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution now. I created a separate function for the function. I am using typescript here.

```
window["JSZip"] = JSZip;
      $('#trackerDataTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
          {
            extend: 'excel',
            className: 'btn-primary',
            text: '&nbsp; Export to Excel &nbsp;',
            filename: 'Timecards',
            extension: '.xlsx',
            exportOptions: {
              columns: ':visible'
            },
            customize: function (xlsx) {
              debugger;
              ExportTimecardsWebPart.exportExcel(xlsx); // create separate function
            }
            // customize: function(xlsx) {
            //   debugger;
            //   var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
            //   $('row c[r^="C"]', sheet).attr('s', '50');
            // }
          },
        ],
});
 
 public static exportExcel(xlsx: any): void {
    debugger;
    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
    $('row c[r^="C"]', sheet).attr('s', '50');
  }
```